# java mouse and keyboard listener, macro recording

Tags: java, macros, listeners

If i read correctly, the mouse and keyboard listeners are intended to capture movement within an application. what I want to do is capture movement system wide.
Mouse movement/clicks and button presses.

Ideally i would like a manner of capturing this movement and being able to replay it by passing appropriate commands to the robot class. Does this seem reasonable, or am i going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you create transparent full screen window and capture events on it. 
To replay the events use class java.awt.Robot.

Use this resource for more info how to create transparent window:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

Comment: If There is an overlaying transparant window, will i be able to actually click the buttons etc on the underlying windows? or will it only be able to capture the movement?